# Adding external Jar file to Android Application using Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I'm trying to add a simple jar file which contains some statics.
I have created a libs folder and copy the jar into. I have configure the project's build path in the Eclipse IDE.
In one of the project's classes i have a referance to one of the static members of the jar file, but it failde to build and the jar's classes are unseen to the application and the Eclipse mark it as an error.
How it can be solved?
Thanks,
Eyal.

Comment: Are your `import`'ing the package correctly at the top of your .java source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#addexternallibrary

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using the libs folder for hosting the jar file.